# How can i send an SMS from .NET 1.1?

Tags: c#, sms, .net-1.1

#### Duplicate

> [C#  && SMS Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%20sms)

I am working in the .net framework 1.1 .. from my application i need to send a SMS to a mobile. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of SMS-gateway services for bulk-sms senders. All of them provide a (custom) API. Ususaly you just craft a special HTTP request. These API's can be used in any language, so .net as well.

Each carrier has its own rates, so do some price comparison. I don't know in which country you are (something Scandinavian?) so I cannot recommend anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send a SMS to a phone, you'll probably need the services of a [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway). However, if the volume of messages you need to send is not that high and you can foot the cost per SMS yourself, you could look at how to use your phone as a modem over USB or COM and send it the message that way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an HTTP API that will enable you to send sms from your application. Something like http://sms.yuboto.com/http-api